# RESTfully Nesting Resource Routes with Single Identifiers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, resources, nested, routes

In my Rails app I have a fairly standard has_many relationship between two entities. A `Foo` has zero or more `Bars`; a `Bar` belongs to exactly one `Foo`. Both Foo and Bar are identified by a single integer ID value. These values are unique across all of their respective instances.

Bar is existence dependent on Foo: it makes no sense to have a Bar without a Foo.

There's two ways to RESTfully references instances of these classes. Given a Foo.id of "100" and a Bar.id of "200":

1. Reference each Foo and Bar through their own "top-level" URL routes, like so:

   - /foo/100
   - /bar/200
2. Reference Bar as a nested resource through its instance of Foo:

   - /foo/100
   - /foo/100/bar/200

I like the nested routes in #2 as it more closely represents the actual dependency relationship between the entities. However, it does seem to involve a lot of extra work for very little gain. Assuming that I know about a particular Bar, I don't need to be told about a particular Foo; I can derive that from the Bar itself. In fact, I probably should be validating the routed Foo everywhere I go (so that you couldn't do /foo/150/bar/200, assuming Bar 200 is not assigned to Foo 150). Ultimately, I don't see what this brings me.

So, are there any *other* arguments for or against these two routing schemes?

### Point of Clarification

I'm concerned mostly about RESTful updates/shows/deletes to particular Bars. For getting a list of Bars for a specific Foo (which is usually the "index" action in Rails) it makes perfect sense to have a nested route such as /foo/100/bar. The page at this route could just as easily link to /bar/x as /foo/100/bar/x though.

Comment: +1 Brilliant question; I've been trying to figure this out lately.

Comment: Here's hoping for a brilliant answer to go along with it. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for shallow routes. As you pointed out, the idea of having a deeply nested route for things like creates, updates is unnecessary since you are targeting the desired record directly.

I have never actually done the shallow routing thing so I'll pass on the railscast episode where Ryan Bates explains it probably better than I could: [139 Nested Resources](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources).

Edit: You can read up a little more on the [guides for routing 3.8.4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: FWIW: I deleted the "create" part, as a nested route is actually *very* useful: it lets me fill in the FK field in Bar without having to retrieve it from the posted parameters; it gets it from the route values instead.

However, it still applies for updates, shows, and deletes (which I just added)

Comment: As usual, Railscasts has all the answers. Shallow routes has the best of both worlds. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry to see it's not all the way there in Rails 3, yet. But, I'm glad you figured out a solution for the time being :)

Answer (score 4):

As you already know, every item has to have a unique address.  I would suggest that the shorter and easier the address is, the better for everyone involved - your routing code, your client apps, etc.  If you can identify a Bar by its unique ID, I would probably specify only that in the URL.

You don't need to lose the semantic information about the Bar's assignment to a Foo, though.  That can be part of the representation.

As an enhancement, you could allow the client to address Bar 200 as /foo/100/bar/200, but then redirect to the preferred /bar/200/ address, using, e.g., a 303 ("See Other") response.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. You could even go as far as to presume that the ID of the Foo is irrelevant, and thus not bother checking for it. Also: rather than a client-side redirect, you could just do a new route pointing to the same controller/action.

Comment: @Craig - agreed, but if you have a preferred URI, then with a client-side redirect, you can educate the client.  (In the admittedly unlikely event that the client program is keeping track of those things.)

Answer (score 2):

Rails' [shallow nesting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) gives us the best of both worlds: it lets us have Foo-specific routes where it makes sense (create, new, index) and Bar-only routes otherwise (show, edit, update, destroy).

Unfortunately, the new routing DSL in Rails 3 (which I'm using) does *not* support shallow routing yet (as of Beta 3). It appears to be [in the works](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3765-missing-shallow-routes-in-new-router-dsl) but it's not functional for today.

However, you can fake it by mapping the resource twice, once nested and once shallow:

```
resources :foo do
  resources :bar, :only => [:index, :new, :create]    
end
resources :bar, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

This will tide me over until the :shallow option is up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if each Bar is dependent on a Foo, option #2 makes more sense. For example, if Foo is a blog and Bar is a post, it is far more logical to access a particular post at `example.bloghosting.com/blog/1/post/2` than `example.bloghosting.com/post/21`.

Do do this with the latest version of Rails:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :foo
end
```

Then, in the Rails router (/config/routes.rb):

```
map.resources :foos do |foo|
    foo.resource :bars
end
```

For more information, see [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) and [the Rails API Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html).

Comment: I agree that it's more logical from a URL point of vieew. However, what I'm asking is whether it's really necessary/beneficial. So far I don't see enough benefit to make it worth the cost.

Comment: How beneficial your URL structure is to the user is dependent mainly on how easily it gives them a sense of your program's model. Hence, the closer the URL structure matches the external model of interaction for your program, the better.

As for the cost... simply changing map.resources :foos to the above code is hardly a cost. If you mean usability cost, I would argue that the marginally longer URLs that better match your program's structure are superior to shorter URLs that don't.

Comment: The cost isn't just in changing the routing. You also need to change the calls to the named route methods and probably should be adding parent-object validation to the controller methods as well.

Comment: It's true that there is additional cost beyond the change in routing. Have you already implemented the old routes? If so, you could use the :shallow option as a temporary measure to transfer your routes over to the new system gradually.

Comment: FWIW, Rails' shallow routes (see the accepted answer) makes the cost much less, meaning that the benefits of the logical URLs is probably worth it.