# Thoughts regarding model ids in rails routes and validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, routes

I am new to RoR and started working on a typical 'has_many' association (ie. a user has many friends). I have everything working correctly, but I don't like having the ids exposed in the url. I find that I need to add extra validation in my controller to make sure the ids represent valid associations in case the user manually entered different ids.

Personally I would like to see the ids out of the url and passed via some other means but that is not always possible. Shallow nesting of resources will help reduce the number of ids I need to validate at least.

What is the RoR philosophy on this? I have not seen anything specific to this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the URL has parameters if it is a GET url.

Try using POST parameters, which means your url will no longer be cluttered. Note that a malicious user can still send a made-up POST request using curl.

Comment: This question is related to mine in case anyone is interested (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892394/restfully-nesting-resource-routes-with-single-identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this is implementing proper authorization. If the user requests information for an object he is not permitted to read, this should be handled by an authorization framework.
With [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or [Declarative Authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) you can define rules that replace your "manual" (and error-prone) checks in controllers.

I like the IDs being in the URL. That is what REST is about. Getting information for specific Resources, which have to be identified with an ID.

You can use [Friendly ID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) in order to replace the integer ID by a slug (e.g. users/tollbooth instead of users/42).

Answer (score 1):

basically ror routes by default takes `id` as key to generate urls. If you are not fan of id based urls then you can always override urls by using `to_param` inside model.

```
def to_param
  # make sure this field is always present & unique   
  username 
end
```

then by default you will start seeing `username` instead of `id` inside urls

How to find object inside controller actions

> User.find_by_username(params[:id])

If you dont want to do this manually make use of slug gems like [friendly id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)